# Rigify doesn't generate arm controls and 'throws an exception'

Tags: rigging, rigify

so it's me again with yet another Rigify problem.
So I'm using Blender 4.0.2 and I encountered a problem when I'm trying to generate a rig. After finally fixing all the errors, Rigify allowed me to generate a rig, but then I noticed that there are no controls for the arms.

I thought that maybe there's something wrong with them in metarig, so after doing some digging I noticed that my upperarm is attached to a 'Torso' category in a Bone Collection. I thought that this might be a reason why my initial problem occured, so I placed them in an ' Arm (IK)' category and also added 'limbs.arms' to a Rig Type, because they were lacking that too. But now when I'm trying to generate a rig again I get 'Generation has thrown an exception:' in the info log. Any ideas what went wrong? Please help.

Here's a file:  [image]

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the link from the download page into it. That way it will remain available for people reading the question in future.

Comment: Usually, Rigify duplicates the metarig and adds it to the generated animation rig. The bones get a ORG- prefix and are put on the last bone layer (Blender 2.x/3) or into the ORG bone collection (Blender 4). This duplication doesn't work for your metarig for some reason (AssertionError). Please note that the metarig is used to create the bone layout and adapt the rig to the model. It usually has no IK constraints, pole, or IK targets because these control bones are generated by Rigify. The correct *Rig Type* is important, the "category"/collection doesn't matter.